# IAR: Differences between a debug probe and a trace probe

Tags: debugging, trace, iar, probe

I am currently entering in the wonderfull world of embedded programming. I have a big port project. I have to port a firmware (which sources are in a bad state) from an ARMv4T (ARM7TDMI) to an ARMv7-M (ARM Cortex-M3).

Right, so I'm getting started with the IAR IDE. For debugging, I knew that hardware debug probe exists, but my getting started guide also mention trace probe. As I love having everythings in control, I wonder **what are the differences between debug probe and trace probe**.

I've googled it but "debug" "probe" and "trace" are too big keywords to find an explanation instead of commercial site.. I've seen that trace probe contains much more memory than a debug probe (that goes from a few MB to more than 1GB o_O ).

MaXx

Comment: Ok boys, I get my anwser. In fact, debug probe can support Trace Function. I don't think specifically Trace probes exist. The Trace function is used to trace the way the program is running, simply by saving all instructions executed. Thoses saved instruction are first saved in the probe and come up to the IDE only when the microC stops (breakpoint). That's why probe memory is needed. Trace can be activated/disactivated by special breakpoints in IAR workbench IDE.

Comment: Trace Probes do exist. Segger's J-Trace is an example. Typically, a trace probe will have a parallel bus of some sort and can capture most if not all of the processor info as it runs. With the Cortex-M cores from ARM, there is an internal trace module that can output via serial wire view/output (SWV/SWO) if your debug probe supports it, but this will typically return a small percentage of actual PC samples. Unless you come across a particularly heinous crash or need to validate code coverage, you likely won't need true trace.